# How can I connect my meta profile with my main Stack Overflow one?

Tags: support, openid, merge-accounts, google

I just signed up in meta.stackoverflow.com and created an account using my OpenID profile. At the end of my registration I think there was a question to "connect" this profile with my other one in the main stackoverflow.com. However, I believe when I registered there it was simply with my Google mail and not with [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), so the system rightly said that it couldn't find the respective profile/account on stackoverflow.com.

- Is it possible to connect these two accounts now?
- What are the advantages, if any?
- Since my OpenID is registered on the same mail (Google) shouldn't this have happened automatically anyway?

Comment: Quick note - this post refers to MSE as it is now, not MSO, and OpenID's no longer a thing. While I considered closing this as no repro, this is probably just as true for other sites.

Answer (score 2):

Go here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136356?tab=accounts#sort-top to associate them.

Advantages:

- +100 rep on each account if at least one has > 200 currently
- ???

Google's OpenIDs are unique per site, which is the reason (well, at least one of the reasons anyway) the accounts had to be linked in the first place.

Comment: I go to that page, but cannot see how to connect?

Answer (score 1):

On your profile page, click on the "Accounts" tab; it leads you through it gently from there...

Advantages: a free 100pts for you (if you have an established account), easier support for us

Gmail might be a pain; IIRC I used my (also google) blogger address while linking, but it might work (I just didn't really try).